# facebook publish_action permission for post link on friend's wall works only for whose already have our android app in facebook application list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I am trying to post link on my friend's wall, for that was added publish_action permission, but it works only for friends whose already have my andorid app in facebook application list.

Is there any way to post link on any friend's wall whose have our app or not in facebook app list?

Comment: Don't post on other people walls. If you can I think it is a bug

Comment: @WizKid thanks for giving me reply, It means facebook graph api is not giving support for post anything on friend's wall

Comment: Correct. If you want a friend something use a the send or message dialog

Comment: it´s spam, and not possible (anymore) to post on another wall except for the authorized user.